# Wired Tiger Error on Mongodb after bad shutdown of Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

So, I shutdown my computer without fully shutting down mongodb services and when I tried to run 'mongod' I was met with an error that a file was damaged so I repaired it using 'mongod --repair' and now I am met with this error:

{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.002-08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1644947710:2946][53343:0x7f12d7777c80], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.003-08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1644947710:3221][53343:0x7f12d7777c80], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.003-08:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1644947710:3451][53343:0x7f12d7777c80], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 808: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.003-08:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.003-08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"13: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.003-08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":687}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-15T09:55:10.003-08:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

What should I do to get mongodb services running again? I've already uninstalled and re-installed mongodb locally.

Thank you for your knowledge and time.

Comment: it looks like your mongod process do not have ,  sufficient permissions to access files inside the data folder: Permission denied  , better to chown mongo -R /<the data folder>  & chmod -R 0775 /<data folder> assuming your mongod service is running under mongo user ...

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I uninstalled and reinstalled mongodb. The problem seems to be solved. I appreciate your time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

So I uninstalled and reinstalled MongoDB. The problem seems to be solved.